# If $A$ is a $5 \times 5$ complex matrix with $A^4=A^2 \neq A$, then what are its possible minimal polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

For this I have that $A^4-A^2=0$ so any possible minimal polynomial must divide $t^4-t^2=t^2(t-1)(t+1)$. Using the given condition I've been able to check that e.g. $A=-I$ works for $t+1$ so $t+1$ is a possible minimal polynomial, but $t-1$ is not possible since $A=I \implies A=A^2$.

Similarly for $(t-1)(t+1)=t^2-1$ we can find a matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2=I$ but $A \neq -I$ so this is also possible.

But there are many other possible polynomials including $t^2+t$, $t^3-t$, $t^2$, $t^3+t^2$, $t^3-t^2$ and $t^4-t^2$ that also divide $t^4-t^2$ and it seems either quite hard or very tedious to construct a $5 \times 5$ matrix satisfying one of these polynomials and checking that it doesn't satisfy any of the lower degree ones (unless it's a simple case like $t^2-t=0 \implies A^2=A$ so that one doesn't work). How do I find which of these are possible minimal polynomials?

Comment: For constructing such matrices: Are you familiar with [Jordan canonical/normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)?

Comment: @prets Ah, so is the intention here to consider the sizes of the blocks in the JNF by considering the multiplicities of each of the roots of the minimal polynomial?

Comment: That's certainly a way to construct matrices, yes! And the shape of those blocks will let you quickly rule out the problematic options like $t^2 - t = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The hypotheses mean that $X^4-X^2$ is an annihilating polynomial of $A$ but $X^2-X$ is not. As you remarked $X^4-X^2$ factors as $X^2(X-1)(X+1)$ and one also has $X^2-X=X(X-1)$. The minimal polynomial must divide the former but not the latter (and it must be monic). The monic divisors of $X^2(X-1)(X+1)$ are $X^a(X-1)^b(X+1)^c$ with $a\in\{0,1,2\}$ and $b,c\in\{0,1\}$; of these $12$ candidates those with $a\leq1$ and $c=0$ are disqualified for dividing $X(X-1)$. There are $4$ of the latter which leaves $8$ viable candidates, where $(a,b,c)$ runs over the set $\{(0,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,1),(2,0,0),(2,0,1),(2,1,0),(2,1,1)\}$.

It remains to be seen whether each of these $8$ polynomial$~P$ can be realised as minimal polynomial of a $5\times 5$ complex matrix. Since $\deg(P)$ is some $d\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, the answer is yes: we can make a square matrix of the size$~d$ by taking the companion matrix of$~P$, and we can complete that to a block diagonal matrix of size $5\times 5$ by taking for the remaining $5-d$ factors for instance $\lambda I_{5-d}$ where $\lambda$ is any root of$~P$ (and it has at least one since $\deg(P)>0$). For instance for $P=X+1$ (with $(a,b,c)=(0,0,1)$) one gets the matrix $-I_5$, and for $P=X^2(X-1)=X^3-X^2$ (with $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0)$) one gets for instance (taking the root $\lambda=1$)
$$\pmatrix{0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1},$$
and the other cases are similar. No Jordan normal forms are needed (though you can use them if you must), nor for that matter complex numbers (as the polynomials split over$~\Bbb Q$).